# oauth2 on office365 smtp with curl error 530 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail

Tags: microsoft-office-365, curl, oauth

I am using this curl:

```
curl -vvv --url 'smtp://smtp.office365.com:587' \
--ssl-reqd \
--mail-from "$user" \
--mail-rcpt "$destuser" \
--upload-file ./mail.txt \
--oauth2-bearer $accesstoken
```

to try to send an email from an account where I registered an oauth application with these Graph Permission - Delegated Permissions

```
SMTP.Send
Mail.Read
Mail.Send
openid
offline_access
```

but I always get error:
*530 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail.*

both the user mailbox and the transport have
SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled to $false

I am quite confident that the access token is valid, I also tested the refresh token which works,
any idea on how to make this work?

Is curl compatible with
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

?

Comment: managed to authenitcate manually with:
XOAUTH2="user=$user\001auth=Bearer $token\001\001"
echo -en $XOAUTH2 | base64 > encodedtoken.txt
tr -d '\n' < encodedtoken.txt > encnonewline.txt

helo="myserver.com"
from='sender@test.com'
to='dest@gmail.com'
subj="subject: test mail"
data=" hello test mail"
encoded2=$( cat encnonewline.txt )

Comment: {

    sleep 1
    echo "helo $helo"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "auth xoauth2"
    sleep 1
    echo $encoded2
    sleep 3
    echo "mail from:<$from>"
    sleep 0.5
    echo "rcpt to:<$to>"
    echo "data"
    echo "From: $from"
    echo "To: $to"
    echo "$subj"
    echo
    echo "$data"
    echo "."
    sleep 1
    echo quit
} | timeout 15 openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587 -crlf -starttls smtp > ./output.txt 2>&1


cat ./output.txt

still need to understand how to do with curl